# Is there a way to glob a directory in Ruby but exclude certain directories? 

Tags: ruby, bash, shell

I want to glob a directory to post-process header files.  Yet I want to exclude some directories in the project.  Right now the default way is...

```
Dir["**/*.h"].each { |header|
    puts header
}
```

Seems inefficient to check each header entry manually if it's in an excluded directory.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Don't use globbing, instead use [`Find`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/index.html). Find is designed to give you access to the directories and files as they're encountered, and you programmatically decide when to bail out of a directory and go to the next. See the example on the doc page.

If you want to continue using globbing this will give you a starting place. You can put multiple tests in `reject` or'd together:

```
Dir['**/*.h'].reject{ |f| f['/path/to/skip'] || f[%r{^/another/path/to/skip}] }.each do |filename|
  puts filename
end
```

You can use either fixed-strings or regex in the tests.

Comment: I can't figure out how to use .reject correctly. Does it not support the same wildcards as .glob? Would like to do ...reject{ |f| f['**/*.tmpl.html'] }.each {...

Comment: also no... .reject{
  |f| File.fnmatch('**.tmpl.html', f)
}.each {... :)

Comment: Got it, my understanding of path matching was wrong. double star doesn't mean it will match in any directory, you still need a context directory. Works: .reject {
  |f| File.fnmatch('../../../main/webapp/**.tmpl.html', f)

Comment: I just came back to the answer again, forgot I'd used it already. Wish I could vote it up twice :)

Answer (score 66):

I know this is 4 years late but for anybody else that might run across this question you can exclude from Dir the same way you would exclude from Bash wildcards:

```
Dir["lib/{[!errors/]**/*,*}.rb"]
```

Which will exclude any folder that starts with "errors" you could even omit the `/` and turn it into a wildcard of sorts too if you want.

Comment: same goes for files in case thats needed too: `Dir.glob "views/{[!partial_]}*.slim"` Explained: You're reading your views dir and every fiule that starts with `partial_` has to be excluded. The remaining .slim files will be listed.

Comment: Can you explain a bit? I am trying to exclude a folder named `to_delete` but only files with name starting with `t,o,d,e,l,t` are being excluded.

Comment: WARNING!  This negation is not quite accurate.  Ruby's implementation of [!...] matches [this description on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)#Unix).  [!errors/] matches one character that is not e,r, o, s, or /.  `[!e][!r][!r][!o][!r][!s][!/]` would match strings that don't begin with "errors/", however, it would not match strings shorter than 7 chararacters. (You can verify this by making some test folders named a, aa, ab, etc. in irb and using Dir.glob to list them).

Answer (score 18):

There's `FileList` from the Rake gem (which is almost always installed by default, and is included in the standard library in Ruby 1.9):

```
files = FileList['**/*.h'].exclude('skip_me')
```

`FileList` has lots of functionality for working with globs efficiently.

You can find the documentation here: http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/FileList.html

Answer (score 11):

```
files = Dir.glob(pattern)
files -= Dir.glob("#{exclude}/**/*")
```

Comment: If the directory tree is large, this is suboptimal because the entire tree is scanned twice.

Answer (score 4):

One way:

```
require 'find'

ignores = ['doc','test','specifications']

Find.find(ENV['HOME']) do |path|
  name = File.basename(path)
  if FileTest.directory?(path)
    if ignores.include?(name)
      Find.prune
    else
      next
    end
  else
    puts path if name =~ /.h$/
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

this is similar to a few other answers just written a bit differently

Ill create an array that can be passed to a .each iteration or something else.

```
release_safelist = Dir.glob('*').reject{ |file|
  (file == "softlinks") || (file == "ci") || (file.include? "SNAPSHOT")
}
```

In this case im creating an array without files/dir named either ci, softlinks, or containing SNAPSHOT

Comment: How can you make it work for a specific hidden directory that you want to exclude?