# Ruby glob: Exclude dir and file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For the import of my Sass files, I use sass-rails' (https://github.com/rails/sass-rails) **glob feature**. It says

> Any valid ruby glob may be used

I want to exclude a directory and a file when using `@import`. **Any ruby code using blocks don't work in this scenario**. But even trying to exclude a single file doesn't work the way I want.

Consider this tree structure

```
/_bar.scss
/_foo.scss
/all.scss
```

For example, I want to exclude the file `_foo.scss`. I read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27707682/228370, using a `!` you can negate a pattern.

I tried the following:

```
Dir["{[!_foo]}*.scss"]
=> ["all.scss"]
```

But this skips `_bar.scss`. When looking into the glob reference of Ruby (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) it becomes clear why:

> [set]
>   Matches any one character in set. Behaves exactly like character sets in Regexp, including set negation ([^a-z]).

(apparently, negation can be achieved with `!` AND `^`)

Because we have an underscore in our pattern, every file with an underscore gets excluded.

**But what would be the solution, to exclude a fixed file?**

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a regex way of doing it.  But if you're talking about one specific file, it might be easier to just do:

```
Dir["*.scss"].reject { |i| i == '_foo.scss' }
```

Comment: Because I need this inside sass along with an `@import`, this won't work. I mentioned this in my question *Any ruby code using blocks don't work in this scenario*